# Reflecting data change (CRUD) in all other places in the flutter application

Tags: php, android, ios, ajax, flutter

I am working on an application using flutter and Mysql DB with PHP Laravel , I have the same post on two different pages (posts come from view in DB).
when I delete or add or edit (do CRUD functionality) that post on the first page the effect does not reflect on the other page in the application (inconsistency), so I must refresh the other page (call API) to show the effect in it.

I try to get all lists that contain posts and search on them to see if a post exists there and do they reflect on it, but there are 3 or 4 lists I need to check every time and this makes the process complex on RAM as a phone application. I also search for something like ajax on the web but I found nothing.

what I need is when I delete or edit the post on the first page this post is also deleted or edited on the second page without doing a refresh.

Comment: You may take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting